# I can only close a form once, InvalidOperation Exception Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi 
I'm opening a form like this from my main form when the user makes a selection of a menu item.

```
private void commToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Command_Form Command_Form1 = new Command_Form();
            Command_Form1.ShowDialog();
           // Command_Form1.Dispose();    this didn't help
        }
```

Inside the form "Command_Form1"
I close it like this when the user clicks on the close button

```
private void Close_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          this.Close();    //I get the exception here 
        }
```

This process works fine once but on the second closing of the form 
(Which I hope is a completely different/new instance of the  form) I get the error in the title of this post.
This is the output in the debug window.

*A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll* 9there are three copies in the debug window if that means anything)

When I step into the Close() method that is where the error is thrown but I'm having difficulty understanding what is going on.  Is there something that I can read to help me understand what is going on inside the close method?

Comment: Your first version of this question at least mentioned you used a SerialPort.  Pretty essential info to help us help you.

Comment: Wait a minute, in a comment below you say "I still end up in the `internal bool CheckCloseDialog(bool closingOnly)` in the catch statment with an exception".  Care to show us this code?  How about the full stack trace of the exception, too?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948087/i-can-only-close-a-form-once-invalidoperation-exception-invoke-or-begininvoke-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From your comment:*

> Becuase the form talks (send/receives
>   data) to a serial port and I need
>   other forms to talk to the same serial
>   port (I don't want two forms to be
>   connected to the serial port at the
>   same time) I think I need to get rid
>   of the one form when I open another
>   form so the hide thing doesn't really
>   work for me. Maybe there is a way to
>   hide and disconnect from the serial
>   port???

*Just a guess:*

Are you subscribing to the `DataReceived` event of the serial port?  If so, are you attempting to access controls or properties on `Command_Form` inside the `DataReceived` handler?  This event can still be raised even when the form is disposed, causing this problem. Before closing the form, you may need to:

- Close the serial port: `port.Close()`, or
- Unregister from the `DataReceived` event: `port.DataReceived -= handler`

Alternatively, you could just Hide the form instead of closing it, if you don't need the port for anything else.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if this is right.  I don't know why the exception would be on the `this.Close()` line...

Comment: I do close the port I do this before I close the form

Comment: private void Form1_FormClosing( object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e ) 
        {
            Program.UserPort1.CloseComPort(Program.UserPort1.SelectedPort); 
            SavePreferences(); 
        }

Comment: Apparently `UserPort1` is not a `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`.  What is it?

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem private void Form1_FormClosing( object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e ) { ComPorts.UserInterfaceData -= new ComPorts.UserInterfaceDataEventHandler(AccessFormMarshal); Program.UserPort1.CloseComPort(Program.UserPort1.SelectedPort); SavePreferences(); }

Comment: It is a class that I use to configure/control the serial port.  I have delegates in that class that marshall the data from the serial port to my form and I have delagtes on the form that marshal the data from the form to the serial port

Comment: because I assume that hey are on a different thread.  I wish I knew what was creating threads in the application I hav threads running around everywhere and I can only guess where they started.

Comment: Because I assume that they are on a different threads i.e. the serial port and the UI form. I wish I knew what was creating threads in the application. I have threads running around everywhere and I can only guess where they started, I certainly didn't fire up any in my code...that I can remember.......can anyone suggest something to read that explains how to work out the secret lives of threads in a .NET app. I found a lot of good stuff that explains what threads are why you use them etc but when I open my threads window in the debugger

Comment: @user59 - SerialPort runs the DataReceived event on a separate thread, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx). [Other threads you see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476642) are the main thread, GC, finalizer, and debug threads.  Do you have a lot more than that?

Comment: Hi Justin I have about six threads in my application so your description sounds right. I found the part in the serial port documentation where the DataReceived event has its own thread (I assumed this much). I reckon if I run outside the debugger the extra threads will be accounted for...except for the ones that you describe above so now things seem to be falling in place. Thanks much